# Why is variable not updated outside of loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can't figure out why the first key from the result is "abc" and not "c" as I'd expect. (I'm using Python 3.6.4)

Data structure is weird because I removed not relevant keys and values.

```
f = { 'replace' : { 'ab' : ''} }

r = {}

data = { 'abc' : 1, 'def' : 2, 'ghi' : 3, 'jkf' : 4, 'lmn' : 5 }
for d in data:
  replaced = 'hello'
  for x in f['replace']:
    if x in d:
      replaced = d.replace(x, f['replace'][x])
      print(replaced)
  else:
      replaced = d
  r.update( { replaced : data[d] } )

print(r)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indenting. You do a `for else` instead of an `if else`, which causes your `replaced` to be overwritten with `d`. You need to indent `else` with two more spaces:

```
f = { 'replace' : { 'ab' : ''} }

r = {}

data = { 'abc' : 1, 'def' : 2, 'ghi' : 3, 'jkf' : 4, 'lmn' : 5 }
for d in data:
  replaced = 'hello'
  for x in f['replace']:
    if x in d:
      replaced = d.replace(x, f['replace'][x])
      print(replaced)
    else:
      replaced = d
  r.update( { replaced : data[d] } )

print(r)
```